# How will we make the below transformation using PIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below

[image]

generated by using the below query

```
declare @t table(Bucket varchar(50), [RollBack] int, [Stabilized] int, [RollForward] int,[Normalized] int)

insert into @t 
    select 'Bucket >6',0,0,100,0 union all
    select 'Bucket 1',0,0,200,0 union all
    select 'Bucket 2',0,0,100,0 union all
    select 'Bucket 3',0,0,100,0 union all
    select 'Bucket 4',0,0,100,0 union all
    select 'Bucket 5',0,0,100,0 union all
    select 'Bucket 6',0,0,100,0

select * from @t
```

I am looking for the below transformation

[image]

My Attempt so far is

```
select a as Activities,

    sum(case when b.Bucket='Bucket 0' then 
                    case when a='RollBack' then [RollBack] 
                         when a='Stabilized' then Stabilized
                         when a='RollForward' then RollForward
                         when a='Normalized' then Normalized                         
                    end else 0 end) as [Bucket 0],

    sum(case when b.Bucket='Bucket 1' then 
                    case when a='RollBack' then [RollBack] 
                         when a='Stabilized' then Stabilized
                         when a='RollForward' then RollForward
                         when a='Normalized' then Normalized                         
                    end else 0 end) as [Bucket 1],

    sum(case when b.Bucket='Bucket 2' then 
                    case when a='RollBack' then [RollBack] 
                         when a='Stabilized' then Stabilized
                         when a='RollForward' then RollForward
                         when a='Normalized' then Normalized                         
                    end else 0 end) as [Bucket 2],

    sum(case when b.Bucket='Bucket 3' then 
                    case when a='RollBack' then [RollBack] 
                         when a='Stabilized' then Stabilized
                         when a='RollForward' then RollForward
                         when a='Normalized' then Normalized                         
                    end else 0 end) as [Bucket 3],

    sum(case when b.Bucket='Bucket 4' then 
                    case when a='RollBack' then [RollBack] 
                         when a='Stabilized' then Stabilized
                         when a='RollForward' then RollForward
                         when a='Normalized' then Normalized                         
                    end else 0 end) as [Bucket 4],

    sum(case when b.Bucket='Bucket 5' then 
                    case when a='RollBack' then [RollBack] 
                         when a='Stabilized' then Stabilized
                         when a='RollForward' then RollForward
                         when a='Normalized' then Normalized                         
                    end else 0 end) as [Bucket 5],

    sum(case when b.Bucket='Bucket 6' then 
                    case when a='RollBack' then [RollBack] 
                         when a='Stabilized' then Stabilized
                         when a='RollForward' then RollForward
                         when a='Normalized' then Normalized                         
                    end else 0 end) as [Bucket 6],

    sum(case when b.Bucket='Bucket >6' then 
                    case when a='RollBack' then [RollBack] 
                         when a='Stabilized' then Stabilized
                         when a='RollForward' then RollForward
                         when a='Normalized' then Normalized                         
                    end else 0 end) as [Bucket >6]

    from (values ('RollBack'),('Stabilized'),('RollForward'),('Normalized')) t(a)
            cross join @t b
            group by a
```

This gives me

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `APPLY` for rest operation :

```
WITH t AS (
     <aggergate query here>
) 
SELECT t.Activities, tt.vcol, tt.val
FROM t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ('Bucket 0', [Bucket 0]), . . . 
     ) tt (col, val);
```

However, i don't know about your actual data model, so i would just do it with `apply` to `unpivot` data.

Comment: great -  I have solved finally using your suggestion. Thanks.